# RewriteEngine not allowed here

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Some time ago I made a `.htaccess` file and it worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MVC
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I installed it on another machine and I get the Apache error:

```
/home/zalmoksis/www/public/MVC-demo/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here
```

What may be wrong?

---

Some relevant Apache configuration around (if you need something more, just say so):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/zalmoksis/www/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride FileInfo
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/zalmoksis/www/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride FileInfo
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and this:

```
Alias /MVC /home/zalmoksis/www/public/MVC-demo

<Directory /home/zalmoksis/www/public/MVC>
        Options FollowSymlinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Are you sure mod_rewrite.so isn't disabled in httpd.conf?